# QGraphicsItem, how to paint element above the childs?

Tags: qt, pyqt

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsItem
from PyQt5.QtSvg import  QGraphicsSvgItem, QSvgRenderer
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF

class MyItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, parent ):
        super().__init__( parent = parent )

        self.textRect =  QRectF( 0,0,100,100 )

        self.SvgGItem = QGraphicsSvgItem(self)
        self.Svg_renderer = QSvgRenderer("./item.svg")
        self.SvgGItem.setSharedRenderer ( self.Svg_renderer )
        self.SvgGItem.setElementId( "1" )

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        alignFlags = Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
        painter.drawText( self.textRect, alignFlags , "text" )
```

I want the text being above the svg item. This code is for example, the real code is pretty difficult, but the sence is the same. setZValue() does not work in this case and it is clear. There is some way or other decision?

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtSvg import  QGraphicsSvgItem, QSvgRenderer


class MyItem(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.w = 100
        self.h = 100
        self.width = 8
        self.text = "None"

        self.setFlags(MyItem.ItemIsSelectable | MyItem.ItemIsMovable)

    def boundingRect(self):  
        return QRectF(self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h)    

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):  
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.blue, self.width)) 
        rec = self.boundingRect().adjusted(self.width  / 2, 
                                           self.width  / 2, 
                                           -self.width / 2, 
                                           -self.width / 2)
        painter.setBrush(Qt.yellow)
        painter.drawRect(rec)
        painter.setFont(QFont("Arial", 16))
        self.textRect =  QRectF( 0, 0, 100, 100 )
        alignFlags = Qt.AlignCenter  
        painter.drawText( self.textRect, alignFlags , "! text !" )


class MySvg(QGraphicsSvgItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MySvg, self).__init__('blank.svg')    

        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable|
                      QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)        


class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setSceneRect(-200, -200, 400, 400)  
        self.fillScene()

    def fillScene(self): 
        test = MySvg()
        self.addItem(test)

        item = MyItem()
        self.addItem(item)

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.green, 3)) 
        painter.drawRect(self.sceneRect())
        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 3))
        painter.drawText(0, 0, '0')
        painter.drawText(-200, -200, '-200')
        painter.drawText(200, 200, '200')


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()

        self.scene = GraphicsScene()
        self.view  = QGraphicsView(self)        
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.view)
        self.setLayout(hbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution does not meet what the OP requires

Comment: @eyllanesc please a few words why and what should I read to correct?

Comment: The OP has a QGraphicsItem parent who has several children, he wants the parent's painting to be on top of the children